# How to display all stories from the Hacker News API on my React app when loading the website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, frontend, hacker-news-api

I've made a copy of the Hacker News Search but I can't display all stories from the API when I get on my website. No stories appear at all. I have to type something on the searchbar to display them all.

I've fetched the data with axios, I `console.log` the collection and it appears that the data has been successfully fetched because I can see the collection on my console.

The github repo : https://github.com/vnsteven/hacker-news-react

The website : https://vnsteven.github.io/hacker-news-react/

The beginning of my App.js file (src/containers/App.js):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Navbar from '../components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Footer from '../components/Footer/Footer';
import Items from '../components/Items/Items';
import './App.css';
import axios from './axios-hn.js';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    list: [],
    initialList: [],
    favoriteList: [],
    count: 0,
    favoriteCount: 0
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const fetchingData = await axios.get('topstories.json');
      const itemIds = await fetchingData.data;
      const list = [];
      itemIds.forEach((id) => {
        axios.get(`item/${id}.json`).then((res) =>
          list.push({
            id: res.data.id,
            title: res.data.title,
            score: res.data.score,
            url: res.data.url,
            author: res.data.by
          })
        );
      });
      this.setState({ initialList: list });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
```

Comment: what does itemIds show in the console? also it might be better to just add them to the state list instead of an intermediary list. instead of list push try `this.setState({ initialList: [...this.state.initialList, { // the item data }]})`

Comment: itemIds shows an Array of ids. I replaced the push method by this.setState but same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use the ["HackerNews API"](https://github.com/HackerNews/API):

First, the `TopStories` endpoint returns a list of post `ids`. You then need to resolve each `id` into its own `post`. To simplify that, you can take advantage of the [`Promise.all` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). This method resolves when all the `promises` provided in an input array, resolve themselves.

I am also using ["React Hooks"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) to handle state changes. Take a look at how to handle state using `useState` and `useEffect` hooks.

Anyways, here is the code example:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/hackernews-top-10-posts-h73km

Comment: If I want to populate all post `metadata` how can I do that?